# Salvar a latitude e a longitude do usuário em variáveis

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Boa tarde, estou fazendo alguns projetos usando a API do Google Maps e queria saber como guardar os valores da latitude e longitude do usuário em uma variável cada, que serão usadas posteriormente em outras funções, alguém pode me ajudar? Estou usando o seguinte código para pegar a localização:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <p id="demo">Clique no botão para receber sua localização em Latitude e Longitude:</p>
      <button onclick="getLocation()">Clique Aqui</button>
      
      <script>
      var x=document.getElementById("demo");
      function getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation){
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else{
          x.innerHTML="O seu navegador não suporta Geolocalização.";
        }
      }
      function showPosition(position){
          x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
          "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
      }
      </script>
      
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você deseja capturar as coordenadas apenas uma vez e reutilizar em outras páginas uma das alternativas é utilizar o localStorage do navegador. Você também pode optar pelo sessionStorage. Ambos guardam as informações no formato chave/valor. Um exemplo de como utilizar o localStorage

```
var objetoCoordenadas = {
  lat: position.coords.latitude,
  lng: position.coords.longitude
}
```

Salvar no localStorage:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('coordenadas', 
JSON.stringify(objetoCoordenadas));
```

Recuperar valores:

```
let coordenadasUsuario = 
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('coordenadas'));
console.log(coordenadasUsuario.lat);
```

Perceba que o objeto que guarda as coordeadas é convertido em string na hora de guardar, e parseado para JSON na hora de recuperar.

Aqui tem mais informações:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

[https://tableless.com.br/guia-fácil-sobre-usar-localstorage-com-javascript/](https://tableless.com.br/guia-f%C3%A1cil-sobre-usar-localstorage-com-javascript/)

Comment: nuss, mt obrigadoddeu super certo aqui, os links tbm ajudaram mt , me salvou kkkkkk